# Почему функция выводит только первый элемент из переданного массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача такова, функция должна выводить переданный массив из заведомо неизвестного числа элементов. Вместо этого выводится только первый элемент. Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
function createArr() {
    var Arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        Arr[i] = arguments[i];
        return Arr;

    }
}

console.log(createArr(2,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: потому что `return` завершает выполнение функции и возвращает результат на первой итерации цикла

Comment: return внутри цикла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function createArr() {
  var Arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    Arr[i] = arguments[i];
  }
  return Arr;
}

console.log(createArr(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const createArray = (...args) => [...args];

console.log(createArray(2,2,3,4,5,6));
```

```js
function createArr(...args) {
    return [...args];
}

console.log(createArr(2,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Comment: Можно ещё просто [`Array.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)